# How to add a background image to an SVG element

Tags: svg

I'm using this code to create a compass needle on an HTML page (instead of the range input i'm using data derived form a separate software). However, I'd like to add a compass face image behind it. Any ideas how I do that? Thanks (The code is from another thread by @Coderino Javarino) Perhaps you can help if you see this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="range" min="0" max="360" value="0" id="slider" oninput="updateAngle(this.value)">
  <script>
    // Feel free to change or delete any of the code you see in this editor!
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", 200)
      .attr("height", 200)
      .attr('viewBox', '-50 -50 100 100')

    var path_d = "M 0,0 L 0,-10 L 50,0 L 0,10 Z";

    function updateAngle(value) {
      var angle = parseInt(value);
      var data = [{
        angle: angle,
        color: 'black'
      }, {
        angle: (180 + angle) % 360,
        color: 'red'
      }];

      paths = svg.selectAll('path')
        .data(data);

      paths.enter()
        .append('path')
        .attr('d', path_d)
        .merge(paths)
        .style('fill', d => d.color)
        .attr('transform', d => `rotate(${d.angle})`);

      paths.exit().remove();
    }

    updateAngle(0);
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: You can add a style attribute to the svg element. For example after setting the viewBox attribute you can add `.attr("style","background:url('.......whatever.....jpg')"`

Comment: Many thanks for your response @enxaneta. I tried adding that just after the viewbox .attr but it just makes the compass arm disappear? I copied it into W3Schools 'try it' editor to test